# constructor for a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

i am trying to implement a linked list.

List has private variables *head, *tail, count.

I understand the logic in the data structure, but admittedly I am new to C++, so i feel like i may be using the constructor incorrectly.

*head and *tail are list node pointers. list nodes then have pointers to previous and next (doubly linked list).

here is what I tried:

```
List::List():head(), tail(), count(0) {
    head->previous = NULL; 
    head->next = tail;
    tail->previous = head; 
    tail->next = NULL; 
}
```

my program compiles but crashes when it tries to make a new list with this constructor. any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, `head` and `tail` will be null pointers for an empty list so dereferncing them like this:

```
head->previous = NULL;
```

will be undefined behaviour.

The constructor would simply be:

```
List::List() : head(0), tail(0), count(0) {}
```

(or use `nullptr` for `head` and `tail` if your C++ is advanced enough).

If your the type of person who likes dummy nodes at the start and end of your lists, you will need to allocate them before trying to use them:

```
List::List() : count(0) {
    head = new somethingOrOther();
    tail = new somethingOrOther();

    head->previous = NULL; 
    head->next = tail;

    tail->previous = head; 
    tail->next = NULL; 
}
```

This trick is often used to greatly simplify list insertions and deletions since you never have to worry about whether you're inserting at the end or deleting at the start.

The downside is that the list traversals and searches for nodes (including for deletion) must start at `head->next` and finish with `tail->previous` but that's often simpler than worrying about the earlier issues.

Comment: ah, that was it! thank you! i don't understand pointers and memory allocation very well yet, so i'm not even sure what that just did.

basically, i was trying to just trying to make a List that had some head and tail pointer that i could manipulate. i know count(0) set the list's count = 0, so how come head() didn't work and we had to do head = new ListNode(); ?

what was the difference between what I tried to do and what you just did? total newbie here!

Comment: Because `head()` and `head = new ListNode()` do two completely different things. The first default initialises a pointer, the second constructs a new ListNode and assigns a pointer to that ListNode. You should avoid thinking 'I understand what I'm doing and therefore the compiler should too'. The compiler will do *exactly* what you tell it, no more, no less. Therefore it's up to you to understand precisely what all the language constructs you use really do.

Comment: @Tidus, John said it best. `:head()` give you a NULL pointer, like `:head(0)`. Explicitly calling `new` and assigning that to `head` will put a real object behind that pointer so that dereferencing won't be undefined.